# Sparse voxel octree for 3d pathfinding and Manhattan distance

Tags: ai, path-finding

I've been learning about using sparse voxel octree for 3d pathfinding based on Daniel Brewer's chapter in Game AI and his talk at GDC 2015.

One aspect that I'm really confused about is exactly what is considered to be a neightbor of a cell in the tree, and whether using Manhattan distance is alright or not. Let's assume that all the cells are of the same size and consider some cell C. How many neightbors will it have - 6, one for each side of the cube, or 27-1=26, all the cubes "touching" our chosen cell at least in one vertex?

It seems the former 6, but I don't see how that doesn't cause problems if we calculate distances between centers of the cells - it induces a manhattan norm, and there's lots of situations where that fails. I have some intuition why it might not be an issue if you do some type of "post processing" on the found path, but it could simply fail quite badly in finding a good path.

Brewer has mentioned using Manhattan distance throughout the talk as well to allow for easier computations, but: 1, it seems like a very problematic thing to me and 2, it seems to me like Manhattan distance is already being used when moving across neightboring cells of same size, which I would assume where the bulk of the expensive computation happens.

//
EDIT: Adding some examples of where it seems to me that Manhattan distance fails:

[image]

Green path corresponds to the good paths, red to the wrong paths. Technically the the green paths should be drawn in jagged way, as on the grid you can only move vertically/horizontally, but you can imagine that if we zoomed really close to them, that is really what they look like - it's just not visible from this distance.

sI -> eI is an example of the general issue with something like Dijsktra's - the red path has the same length as the green path in Manhattan distance and could get chosen. It would probably work fine with A* if we use something like euclidean distance for the Heuristic, since it will greedily go as close to the obstacle as possible.
sI -> eII shows the same problem, but fails with A* too.

I can imagine that both of the above are not huge issues - the pathfinding finds a general path which is good enough - when it comes to the agent actually following the path, they could for example set its next "target" as the furthest point on the path it can travel to directly (check a raycast/spherecast), or even do a few raycast checks along the line between the last point it can reach directly and the next one - the blue line in the image. We would set the local "target" to be a point on the blue line that is furthest away from the reachable point.

sII -> eIII doesn't seem like something that can be fixed like I described in the paragraph above. A* will simply find the wrong red path.

Comment: You say this use of Manhattan distance seems problematic — can you demonstrate a specific problem with it that we can help you solve?

Comment: @DMGregory I've added an example of what I mean, please let me know if it makes sense.